# PTIJ: is bacon permitted to eat?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

The Talmud ([Chulin 17a](https://www.sefaria.org/Chullin.17a.12)) discusses that certain peices of pig meat are permitted:

> השתא דבר טמא אישתרי להו דכתיב (דברים ו, יא) ובתים מלאים כל טוב ואמר ר' ירמיה בר אבא אמר רב כתלי דחזירי בשר נחירה מבעיא
>
> Now, non-kosher items are permitted for them, as it is written: “And it shall be, when the Lord your God shall bring you into the land that He swore to your fathers, and houses full of all good things…and you shall eat and be satisfied” (Deuteronomy 6:10–11), and Rabbi Yirmeya bar Abba says that Rav says: pieces of pig meat are permitted for them; certainly the meat from the stabbing of a kosher animal is permitted!

[Rashi comments](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Chullin_17a.12.2) on this to qualify the pig meat as bacon.

> כתלי דחזירי - חזירים יבשים שקורין בקונ"ש
>
> Pieces of pig meat - dried out pig meat, which we call bacon.

I know that this is *only* Talmudic dialogue, however, does this law stand until today, what is the modern law?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Closers: you know Ham is like bacon, [right?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/100934/16706)

Comment: I think I am missing the joke. You seem to have just brought a Gemara, correctly, and asked if it applies today, despite the Gemara's context. Asking if a Gemara doesn't mean what it says doesn't seem like Purim Torah to me. If you can ping me to explain what I am missing, I'll retract my close vote.

Comment: @Yez The joke is in the context of the Gemara, which Dr. Shmuel conveniently left out. The Gemara is discussing whether soldiers during wartime can eat treif. It’s a deliberate misinterpretation of a Torah text, albeit a poorly worded one. On-topic, and I request a rewrite of the post anyway.

Comment: @DonielF I think my awareness of the context is why I missed the "joke". Even without the surrounding context, it seems obvious that the Gemara is discussing a specific and contained allowance. Which is why the question seems to boil down to "the Gemara gave a temporary and circumstantial allowance for pig meat. Does it still apply?"

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about bacon *per se* but perhaps pork is allowed, since it says in Shabbos davening before Mussaf:

> יקום **פורק**ן מן שמיא